# how do tell if its better to standardize your data matrix first when you do principal component analysis in R?

Tags: r, statistics, pca, numerical-methods

I'm trying to do principal component analysis in R . There are 2 ways of doing it, I believe.
One is doing principal component analysis right away the other way is standardizing the matrix first using `s = scale(m)` and then applying principal component analysis.
How do I tell what result is better? What values, in particular, should I look at? I already managed to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, the proportion of variance for each eigenvector using both methods.

I noticed that the proportion of the variance for the first pca without standardizing had a larger value. Is there a meaning to it? Isn't this always the case?

At last, if I am supposed to predict a variable ie weight should I drop the variable ie weight from my data matrix when I do a principal component analysis?

Comment: i think it depends on what you mean by 'better', and i'm not being sarcastic or dismissive, just pointing out, i dont know if there's a easy answer until its clear what the question under consideration is (as hadley eludes to)

Answer (score 3):

Are your variables measured on a common scale?  If yes, then don't scale.  If no, then it's probably a good idea to scale.

If you are trying to predict the value of another variable, PCA is probably not the correct tool.  Maybe you should look at a regression model instead.

Comment: but how do I find out if my variables are measured on a common scale ?